# Need to replace particular code in Notepad++ regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

i have around 200 html files which will be edited in Notepad++ and in those 200 files i need to edit 1 particular line in every html file

Here is the code that i need to change

```
<p class="explain_para"><b>Different Text</b></p>
```

To

```
<h3>Same text of the above explain para class which needs to edit</h3>
```

In short i want to remove `<p class="explain_para"><b> </b></p>` to `<h3></h3>`

Any solution?

Comment: What is the source of the replacement text?

Comment: What to do you mean by source?

Comment: You are suggesting a regex transformation of some portion of your current text, to some new output.  What is the starting point?

Comment: <p class="explain_para"><b> is the starting point

Comment: *"i have around 200 html files [...] i need to edit 1 particular line in every html file"* - that sounds more like a job for a programming language and a loop than for manual work in a text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Find in Files**
**Find What:** `<p class="explain_para"><b>(.*?)</b></p>`
**Replace With:** `<h3>\1</h3>`
**Regular Expression:** Yes
**`.` Matches newline:** Yes
<kbd>Replace in Files</kbd>

I would however instead create a script in some programming language (Python, VBScript, C++, Java, grep in bash, ...) that loops over your files, and performs this change. Once created, it is reusable, runnable with one click, easy to adapt when it had to be done a little differently, ...etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace in all html files with:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `<p class="explain_para"><b>(.*?)</b></p>`
- Replace with: `<h3>$1</h3>`
- Filters: `*.html`
- Directory: `Path\where\your\files\are`
- **UNCHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace in Files</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<p class="explain_para"><b>     # literally
(.*?)                           # group 1, 0 or more any character
</b></p>                        # literally
```

**Replacement:**

```
<h3>            # open tag
$1              # content of group 1 (i.e. the text to keep)
</h3>           # close tag
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: Nice the downvote, may I know why?